# Handling EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Multi-threaded WebSocket Client Using Boost.Asio in C++

Tags: c++, websocket, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I'm developing a multi-threaded WebSocket client in C++ using Boost.Beast and Boost.Asio. I occasionally encounter a segmentation fault (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) during the WebSocket handshake process (do_handshake method). The application is designed to handle real-time data streaming from a server.

**Here is the simplified version of my WebSocketClient class:**

```
class WebSocketClient
{
private:
    OrderBook &orderBook_;
    string coin_;

    boost::asio::io_context ioc_;
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    ssl::context ssl_context_;
    websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>> ws_;

public:
    WebSocketClient(OrderBook &orderBook, const string &coin)
        : orderBook_(orderBook),
          coin_(coin),
          resolver_(ioc_),
          ssl_context_(ssl::context::tlsv12_client),
          ws_(ioc_, ssl_context_)
    {
        ssl_context_.set_default_verify_paths();
        ws_.next_layer().set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
        ws_.next_layer().set_verify_callback(ssl::rfc2818_verification("stream.binance.com"));
    }

    void connectAndSubscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "&ws_ = " << &ws_ << endl;
            // Resolve the host name and connect to the server
            auto const results = resolver_.resolve("stream.binance.com", "9443");
            auto ep = boost::asio::connect(ws_.next_layer().next_layer(), results);
            string host_ = "stream.binance.com:" + to_string(ep.port());

            ws_.next_layer().handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
            // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
            ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::request_type &req)
                {
                    req.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent,
                            string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-client");
                }));

            string path = "/ws/" + coin_ + "@depth5@100ms";
            ws_.handshake(host_, path);
            cout << "Handshake successful." << endl;

            string msg = "{\"method\": \"SUBSCRIBE\", \"params\": [\"" + coin_ + "@depth5@100ms\"], \"id\": 1}";
            send(msg);
            cout << "Subscription request done!" << endl;
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            cout << "Error in connectAndSubscribe: " << e.what() << endl;
            throw; // Rethrow to be caught by the caller
        }
    }
```

The class is used in a multi-threaded context where each thread creates an instance of WebSocketClient to handle its connection. The crash happens sporadically, and the stack trace points to the do_handshake method.

I have reviewed the object lifetimes, and the objects like ssl_context_, resolver_, and ws_ are members of the WebSocketClient class. I ensure that the OrderBook object outlives the WebSocketClient instances.

**lldb terminal:**

```
* thread #5, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x000000010003a28b adabtc`void boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> >, true>::do_handshake<void (*)(boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::empty_body, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::__1::allocator<char> > >&)>(boost::beast::http::message<false, boost::beast::http::basic_string_body<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::__1::allocator<char> > >*, boost::core::basic_string_view<char>, boost::core::basic_string_view<char>, void (* const&)(boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::empty_body, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::__1::allocator<char> > >&), boost::system::error_code&) + 843
adabtc`boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::any_io_executor> >, true>::do_handshake<void (*)(boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::empty_body, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::__1::allocator<char> > >&)>:
->  0x10003a28b <+843>: vmovaps 0x40(%rax), %ymm0
    0x10003a290 <+848>: leaq   0x2210(%rsp), %rax
    0x10003a298 <+856>: vmovups %ymm0, (%rax)
    0x10003a29c <+860>: movq   %r13, %r12
Target 0: (adabtc) stopped.
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not a C++ exception. It's general protection fault. Your job is not to handle them, but to avoid them. Clearly you have UB, most likely a data race. Fix that, or post a self-contained example so we can review. Here's my start from your code - that's all the 20 minutes I had for now:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0441d61a2057cc14)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace net       = boost::asio;
namespace ssl       = net::ssl;
namespace http      = boost::beast::http;
namespace websocket = boost::beast::websocket;
using net::ip::tcp;
struct OrderBook {
};

struct WebSocketClient {
    using Socket = tcp::socket;
    using Stream = ssl::stream<Socket>;
    using WS     = websocket::stream<Stream>;

    net::io_context ioc_;
    OrderBook&      orderBook_;
    std::string     coin_;
    tcp::resolver   resolver_{ioc_};
    ssl::context    ssl_context_{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    WS              ws_{ioc_, ssl_context_};

    WebSocketClient(OrderBook& orderBook, std::string coin) : orderBook_(orderBook), coin_(std::move(coin)) {
        ssl_context_.set_default_verify_paths();
        ws_.next_layer().set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
        ws_.next_layer().set_verify_callback(ssl::rfc2818_verification("stream.binance.com"));
    }

    void send(std::string msg) {
        ws_.write(net::buffer(msg));
    }

    void connectAndSubscribe() {
        // std::cout << "&ws_ = " << &ws_ << std::endl;

        // Resolve the host name and connect to the server
        auto results = resolver_.resolve("stream.binance.com", "9443");
        auto ep      = connect(ws_.next_layer().next_layer(), results);
        auto host_   = "stream.binance.com:" + std::to_string(ep.port());

        ws_.next_layer().handshake(Stream::client);
        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::request_type& req) {
            req.set(http::field::user_agent, std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-client");
        }));

        std::string path = "/ws/" + coin_ + "@depth5@100ms";
        ws_.handshake(host_, path);
        std::cout << "Handshake successful." << std::endl;

        // std::string msg = R"({"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": [")" + coin_ + R"(@depth5@100ms"], "id": 1})";
        std::string msg = serialize(boost::json::value{
            {"method", "SUBSCRIBE"},
            {"params", {coin_ + "@depth5@100ms"}},
            {"id", 1},
        });
        // msg = R"({"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": [")" + coin_ + R"(@depth5@100ms"], "id": 1})";

        send(msg);
        std::cout << "Subscription request done!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    OrderBook ob;
    WebSocketClient x(ob, "USD");
    x.connectAndSubscribe();
}
```

Which on my machine prints the expected

```
Handshake successful.
Subscription request done!
```

> The application is designed to handle real-time data streaming from a server

I highly doubt it because I'd expect thread-awareness AND asynchronous IO instead.

Please extend the minimal self-contained code to reproduce your error. Or simply show how the reading is organized and how thread synchronization is done on the order book.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the clarification. Yet with your implementation, I can't even compile the rest of my class. How did you implement the read method? I am using async_read and now I moved from segfault to not compiling at all.  Error: "Unknown Socket type in async_teardown."

Comment: I see you didn't update the question code, so I really can't tell. As you can see, I spent all my time making your code self-contained, so maybe you can take that as a starting point and post the actual code so we *can help* with it

Comment: i have created a new question with a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681029/compilation-error-with-boost-beast-websocket-in-c-project

Comment: @PedroSouto That's a good idea. However, it still doesn't show anything relevant to review the threading bug(s). I will note that you need to have more intentional naming (`read` -> `readLoop`) and scope (only make `public:` what users may call). Then, `send` is likely a data race if multiple threads can invoke it, next up, `OrderBook::update` needs thread synchronization which you may or may not have. In principle, the `readLoop` is logically single-threaded, so no worries there. The largest missing piece is what ever runs `ioc_`. It's weird. I'd expect a global thread pool to run all clients